# findViewById marked red

Tags: android, android-studio, findviewbyid

why is the word `findViewById` red ? i made a tabbed activity and this is one of the 3 screens that you can switch to.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thekairi78, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Now the rootView is red

Answer (score 2):

`findViewById` is a method of `View` or `Activity`, it cannot be called directly in fragments.

Corrected code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thekairi78, container, false);  
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    return rootView;  
}
```

---

Try to not only use this, but to understand why this change has to be made. It'll help you in further developing.

Comment: Thanks but now the app crash i can't even launch it

Comment: That means you're doing something fundamentally wrong. Debug your code.

Comment: i did it and dat change nothing

Comment: you don't seem to know what that means. Read some tutorials

Comment: lol. @Quentin Mayer post your error log at least so we can help you better.

Comment: 06-16 18:58:23.107 18929-18929/com.hendek.quentin.theapplication78 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.hendek.quentin.theapplication78, PID: 18929
                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference